# SUM when Running Total Negative and Positive

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

First time posting a question here and I'm new to DAX, hope the experts here can guide me thru my problem.

I have tables whose relationship as shown
[Tables relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik0xm.png)

**1. DC_SOH:** Calculate stock at the end month after considering in/out the transaction

```
DC SOH = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('DC SOH'[Unrestricted Stock]) - SUM('SNP'[Dependent Demand]) - SUM(SNP[Distr. Demand (TLB)])  - SUM(SNP[Distr.Demand (Conf)]) + Sum(SNP[In Transit]) + sum(SNP[Distr. Receipt (TLB)]) + sum(SNP[DistrReceipt (Conf)]) - Sum('MTD Attainment'[Current Fcst]) - Sum('MTD Attainment'[Free Forecast]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Calendar'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Calendar'[Date], MAX('SNP'[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

**2. Calculate Supply based on DC_SOH**

```
Supply = 
VAR DC_SOH = CALCULATE(
    SUM('DC SOH'[Unrestricted Stock]) - SUM('SNP'[Dependent Demand]) - SUM(SNP[Distr. Demand (TLB)])  - SUM(SNP[Distr.Demand (Conf)]) + Sum(SNP[In Transit]) + sum(SNP[Distr. Receipt (TLB)]) + sum(SNP[DistrReceipt (Conf)]) - Sum('MTD Attainment'[Current Fcst]) - Sum('MTD Attainment'[Free Forecast]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Calendar'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Calendar'[Date], MAX('SNP'[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
VAR Ttl_Fcst = sum('MTD Attainment'[Current Fcst]) + SUM('MTD Attainment'[Free Forecast])
RETURN
sumx(SNP, if(DC_SOH > 0, Ttl_Fcst))
```

My question:

1. Total Sum is not right, could you explain why it returns to a very big number which I don't recognize
   [Sum_Supply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmWMA.png)
2. Result i want to achieve:
   if DC SOH > 0 => total forecast => 100% supportable
   if DC SOH < 0 => Original DC SOH => partial supportable
   Here is example
   [example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKr1b.png)

Any advice is much appreciated :)